# Custom checkbox - SVG background image not visible in IE11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I am trying to make pure css custom checkboxes based on Bootstrap 4 custom forms. Checkboxes work fine on all browsers except IE11 on Windows 10 (IE11 + Windows 7 works fine). Strange thing: it is starting to work when I select all text using mouse cursor mouse or I resize browser window - ticks are magically appearing.

This is what i managed to do:

```css
.custom-checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-input:disabled~.custom-checkbox-label {
  color: #6c757d;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-input:disabled~.custom-checkbox-label::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border-color: #c9c9c9;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-input::checked~.custom-checkbox-label::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-input::checked~.custom-checkbox-label::after {
  background-color: red;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-input:checked~.custom-checkbox-label::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%230065F9' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-input:disabled:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23a4c8fc' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-label::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: "";
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #0065F9;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-checkbox-label::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 65% 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-checkbox-label" for="customCheck1">
      Check this custom checkbox
    </label>
</div>
```